# cpp issue with wide char and windows functions

Tags: c++

```
static void GetFilesFromDir(std::string dir, std::vector<std::string>& items)
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA findData;
    HANDLE hFind=FindFirstFile((dir+"\\*").c_str(), &findData); //1 error
    do
    {
        if(hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            std::string sFileName = findData.cFileName; //2 error
            LPCSTR lp(sFileName.c_str());

            if(sFileName == "." || sFileName == "..")
            {} //do nothing
            else if (findData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
                GetFilesFromDir(dir+"\\"+sFileName, items);
            else
                items.push_back(dir+"\\"+sFileName);
        }

    }   while (FindNextFile(hFind, &findData));
}
```

So here's my simple function that I just coppied from another project to the new one. And it throws errors for no reason I can think of, especially because it works in other projects...

```
1>c:\users\prog\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\vampire stealth\vampire    stealth\smallfunctions.h(22): error C2664: 'FindFirstFileW' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char *' to 'LPCWSTR'
1>          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

1>c:\users\prog\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\vampire stealth\vampire stealth\smallfunctions.h(27): error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'WCHAR [260]' to 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
```

Anyone has any ideas on what's wrong? I'm totally clueless about it.

Comment: `std::wstring` holds wide characters.

Comment: but i dont want wstrings, and for some reason compiler thinks I do? why?

Comment: You have `UNICODE` defined somewhere.

Comment: Have you tried using `FindFirstFileA`?

Comment: @user974967, Better to change the #define than call the A version of every function you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first error:

```
...(dir+L"\\*").c_str()...
```

second error:

```
std::wstring wFileName = findData.cFileName;
```

I think you have set the UNICODE flag for the project, so you need to use wide characters.
wchar_t intead of char and wstring instead of string.

Comment: How to change the unicode flag back to normal? I'm using VC 2k10.

Comment: Okay I found it in project's proporties.